# Controller with multi action in Express.JS?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm making routing by Express. my app load all controllers and each controller has multi action. However, in my controller, Express Router just load default action in my controller and error with all others

> Cannot GET /index/action1234

For more specific, this is my code.
The route in app.js

```
fs.readdirSync('./controllers').forEach(function (file) {
    if(file.substr(-3) == '.js') {
        app.use(require('./controllers/' + file));
    }
});
```

The controller index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("index/index");
});
router.get('/:action', function(req, res) {
    res.send("index/"+req.params.action);
});
module.exports = router;
```

Do I have to pass the "app" param to controller and use this instead of router module?
Thanks

Comment: hum ....actually your app handle `/action1234` but not `/index/action1234`

Comment: Yes, My mistake is that's not nested router.

Comment: you could put `/index` as a first argument in `app.use(require('./controllers/ + file));` but it would do it for all your futur route or you coulb put all your "prefix" route in an array with the same order as your files in controller's directory and iterate over it. But it means you have to fill this array every time you create a controller

Comment: @mJehanno Thank you! But I solved my problem with a bit advance. I updated an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by put a path param when load all controllers.

```
fs.readdirSync('./controllers').forEach(function (file) {
    if(file.substr(-3) == '.js') {
        app.use('/'+file.substr(0, file.length - 3), require('./controllers/' + file));
    }
});
```

Thanks